# Conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

It seems my solution is using two different versions of System.Web.Mvc.  The question is how do I resolve this so it uses the same version?

> Error 2   Assembly 'SportsStore.WebUI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher
>   version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Answer (score 2):

If you installed the System.Web.mvc extension via Nuget, do an update for every project where you use it through the Nuget package manager;

Otherwise, for every project where you reference System.Web.mvc you could remove the reference manually and add it again (using the same version number everywhere).

Comment: Thanks for this it is something to do with the referencing you just need to delete the old system.web.mvc reference from the project level and add it again.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this in your `web.config` (make sure you do not over write existing sections)

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```